# Modifying Bootstrap breakpoints after loading from a CDN

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, cdn

I'm currently using a custom version of Bootstrap 3.3.7. Specifically, I changed `@grid-float-breakpoint` from `@screen-sm-min` to `@screen-md-min` to prevent the navbar from spilling over onto two lines.

The Question: I don't want to use this custom version because I can't take advantage of a CDN. Is there a way to load a CDN version and then make this change?

(Also, I couldn't figure out how to avoid the spillover in the navbar without changing the breakpoint, any advice on a better way to do that would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 0):

CSS is hierarchical, so if you write your edited CSS in another stylesheet and link it in your html after the one you pull from the CDN, your edit should take precedence.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Those are LESS variables, so I'll try running a diff on a customised and uncustomised version of the compiled files and see what I need to put in the new CSS stylesheet.

Comment: The only thing that needs to change are a bunch of media queries of this form `@media (min-width: 768px) { CSS rules go here  }`. Needs to change to 992px. But just overwriting them by copying the modified rules into a new file and linking it after bootstrap isn't working, I think because both rules are being applied.

Comment: @nmit026 Unfortunately because it's the media queries' width that need to be changed I think you're right, my method won't work. I don't know of any way to remove or modify a previously defined media query. I'll try to think of a workaround but I think your best bet is probably to not use the CDN.  I will say that it is considered a better practice to not use the CDN for a production environment because it causes your site to have an external dependency and if the CDN goes down you're hosed for a bit.

Comment: It's possible to configure it such that you can fall back to a local copy if your external dependency fails. That's what I always do (using ASP.NET MVC). I'm working on making your method work here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755990/overwriting-media-queries-min-and-max-width?noredirect=1#comment72628039_42755990