# Overwriting media queries - min and max width

Tags: css, media-queries

I have this code in my first CSS file:

```
/* min-width */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-static-top {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}

/* max-width */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-form .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .navbar-form .form-group:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

I have this code in a CSS file linked after the first file:

```
/* min-width */ 
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-static-top {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}

/* max-width */
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-form .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .navbar-form .form-group:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

As you can see, the only difference between the two files is the min-width and max-width values.

I need the code in the second file to overwrite the first file. It needs to be as if the code in the first file doesn't exist. I do not have access to the first file, it's being pulled from a CDN. See this question: [Modifying Bootstrap breakpoints after loading from a CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755280/modifying-bootstrap-breakpoints-after-loading-from-a-cdn/42755306?noredirect=1#comment72628047_42755306). I customised bootstrap by changing the LESS variable `@grid-float-breakpoint` from `@screen-sm-min` to `@screen-md-min` to prevent the navbar from spilling over onto two lines. I diffed the customised and original compiled versions and the only difference was the values of the `min-width` and `max-width` of the media queries. The actual content of the media queries stays the same in both versions.

Comment: just put the second code after the first code, if it still doesn't work, use `!important` to help you

Comment: to be more specific just use like `@media (width: 767px)`. Just a tip

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy I think it's not working because both min-width media queries are being applied? The second min-width doesn't stop the first min-width from firing?

Comment: Do you have access to the first file?

Comment: @nmit026 but the second query will overlap the first

Comment: @Michael_B I should have written that. I'll edit the question. No, it's bootstrap being pulled from a CDN and I'm trying to modify it so I don't have to use a custom version, which uses bandwidth.